# How to handle legitimate improvements mixed with suprerfluous changes in suggested edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

In reviewing the suggested edit queue, I often find a single edit with some readability or formatting improvements, along with other changes that do not improve the post. A few examples of these non-improvements are changing can't to cannot, or correcting Pyhton 2.7 to `Python 2.7` (a typo was fixed, but the backticks are not appropriate).

I've generally been skipping these, as I do not want to lose the real improvements, but I don't want to approve superfluous changes either.

How should I handle this case?

Comment: If you skip such a post, you only defer the decision to the next reviewer which usually results in a skip loop until it hits a more lenient / strict person - although every case is different, I suggest rejecting such an edit in general and making exceptions using your best judgement. There is no point in cluttering the queue with edits that can be done freely by users with >= 2K reputation. When a change leads to 3 established users taking their time to review it, it should be more than just a readability improvement ( and usually posts have plenty to fix: tags, "thank you", titles, etc ).

Comment: as long as they don't hurt or change anything accept it. And else improve the edit.

Comment: @nbk - oh, I forgot another opportunity! Vincent - yes, if you think you can improve the edit, just hit "improve", it will accept the edit and give you the opportunity to educate the user about what else could be done